# Rails with bootstrap installed via yarn can't find fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, yarnpkg

I have a Rails 5 app with Bootstrap which I installed with yarn. I did the following:

`yarn add bootstrap`

```
bootstrap@^3.3.7:
  version "3.3.7"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-3.3.7.tgz#5a389394549f23330875a3b150656574f8a9eb71"
```

on application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap
```

on application.js

```
//= require bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap
//= require rails-ujs
//= require @fnando/sparkline/dist/sparkline
//= require_tree .
```

on assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts')
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << %r{node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/[\w-]+\.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff2?)$}
```

Still, when I access it on production (Heroku) I get

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"):
```

I tried add `$icon-font-path: "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts";` as well to my scss but that also didn't worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem with paths for fonts.
SCSS file for font-awesome `node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_path.scss` has this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
 ...
}
```

But it should be font-url(..) instead of url(..) so font files are precompiled and stored in public/assets.

Override font paths in application.scss:

```
$fa-font-path:"font-awesome/fonts";

@import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
  src: font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=#{$fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
  font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff2'),
  font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff'),
  font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=#{$fa-version}') format('truetype'),
  font-url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=#{$fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  //  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/FontAwesome.otf') format('opentype'); // used when developing fonts
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Run `rake assets:precompile` and you should see font files in `public/assets/font-awesome/fonts` with digested file names.

Compiled CSS should access font files from Rails assets:

```
@font-face{
   font-family:'FontAwesome';
   src:url(/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-7bfcab6db99...979.eot?v=4.7.0)
```